# Why doesn't print module_invoke('user', 'block', 'view', 0); use template files?

Tags: 6, blocks

If I invoke the user login block using module_invoke it doesn't use block-user-0.tpl.php. If I drop the block in the right sidebar and print $right it does use block-user-0.tpl.php.

Also, why will it only print the block once so that printing $right and module_invoke only results in one login form?

Answer (score 1):

The code `module_invoke('user', 'block', 'view', 0)` eventually calls `user_block('view', 0)`. The [user_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_block/6) function returns an array in this case; that's just how hook_block works. The [documentation for hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) says:

> If $op is 'view': return an array which must define a 'subject'
>   element (the localized block title) and a 'content' element (the block
>   body) defining the block indexed by $delta. If the "content" element
>   is empty, no block will be displayed even if "subject" is present.

If you want to know how to render this block, check [this comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_block/6#comment-2643) on the [theme_block documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_block/6) page.

Answer (score 0):

1st:

Call

```
 print drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
```

2nd:

Drupal marks each printed element with

```
$elements['#printed'] = TRUE;
```

so any content cannot be rendered twice. You can modify this value if you need to render twice any element.